# return value for dummy

Tags: java, return

I am completely newbie in java and for now learning proces is going well.But i got stuck with getters,in fact i got stuck with return keyword. I understand how to write return keyword with getters and it will work. But i do not  understand logic behind return keyword. I understand that it's returning value but what does mean "Returning" ? I seriously need someone to explain this method to me and how to use it in simple terms because every website I go on all I see is "to return a return return return return return" and I can't deal with it.

Thank for patience with me :)

Comment: Good question and your confusion is very understandable, but unless someone can explain better than the documentation by the author's of Java language, have you read the Java tutorial's explantation of the `return` statement? [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html